# Animate ejecting bullet brass

Tags: animation

Ok so what I'm trying to do is animate what the title says. I've got my shell casing modeled but I cannot get the fine tuning of the ejection animation proper. I've toyed with rigid body simulation just allowing the casing to drop and collide with a plane so well as particle system emitting casings from a plane not visible in the camera frame. Issue is either way I'm not getting the realism. With particle system I don't get the collision on the plane right seemingly no matter how I tweak things and with rigid body im getting no vertical propulsion of the casings but a decent enough collision with the plane. Has anyone else ever animated this simulation and has advice to offer for methods and tweaking?

Comment: I think you need to upload a gif or something to show what the problem is with the simulation. Try do describe what you are referring to when you say Not realistic. Rigid Body simulations should be the way to go but they might need some tweaking.

Comment: I'll screen record when I get home and upload a short video. My problem with the rigid body method is I get no vertical projection as the casing is in air. Just a straight down drop